# Trying to Filter a Form by Combo Box Value Error: "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to filter a form based off of the value that is selected in a combo box.  The field that I am trying to filter is called "wave" and the combo box is called cboWaveFilter.  I am using the VBA code below to apply the filter.  I tried both the uncommented code and the commented out code and I still receive the same error message.  I keep receiving the error message "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression" when I try to select a value in the combo box.  I can't figure out what is causing this error.  I went back and checked the query that the form is built on (and the subqueries that that query is built from) and I can't find any issue with a space in a field name (which seems to be a common solution to the problem).  Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Thank you!

```
Private Sub cboWaveFilter_AfterUpdate()

'DoCmd.ApplyFilter , "[wave] =" & Me.cboWaveFilter

Me.Filter = "wave =" & Me.cboWaveFilter & "'" 
Me.FilterOn = True

End Sub
```

Comment: you prolly need another singler quote before me.cbowavefilter

Comment: Close, this was what I eventually had to do.  Thank you for your help!

`Me.Filter = "[wavename]='" & Me.cboWaveFilter & "'" `